# "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting this error message when trying to reach my ASP .NET Core 3.1 Web API with Postman:

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

However, I do have configured it using `AddDbContext` in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ..

            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ViewQlikDatabase");
            services.AddDbContext<QlikDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }
```

I have checked the connection string and it is correctly retrieved.
The DbContext also has the recommended constructor:

```
public QlikDbContext(DbContextOptions<QlikDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

The exception is raised when I try to call the context in my business class:

```
public string SedeGetTotaleElementiVista()
    {
        using (var db = new QlikDbContext())
        {
            // Exception raised here
            int count = db.ViewQlikSede.Count();

            return count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context must be *injected*. If you new it up yourself, the service registration doesn't come into play at all. Here, you're creating it yourself, and not passing anything into it, so this instance definitely doesn't have a provider configured.

Comment: That's it, you're right. In fact, I even found the point in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) where it says exactly that. Now it works, thanks.